# Interfacing incompletely documented logic signal where resistor affects output voltage level

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, raspberry-pi, 12v

So I've got this marginally documented 12V logic signal from something I have to regard as a black box that I'd like to interface to a pi or arduino (i.e. c 3V).

I have 3 lines - 0V, +12V and signal (in the 100mA ballpark).  The signal line is either 0 or 12V as per its logic state.  All documented to this point.  I can measure and confirm the behaviour with a meter.

That's all fine, but if I take the 0V and signal lines for the input into another circuit either via a pair of resistors in a voltage divider or a single resistor protecting the input side of an optocoupler, the voltage appears to drop away so low that its useless.

What might be going on here?  Can anyone suggest a way forward, please?  Would a mosfet or similar in front of the optocoupler help?  I know nothing more about the source, but also don't want to damage it.

Comment: What resistor values are you using for that voltage divider? It appears that your "black box" can't drive much current, so you'll need pretty high resistances for the voltage divider. An optocoupler may also draw far more current than your "black box" can supply...

Comment: Maybe the output is open-drain with a very weak pullup?  In any case without documentation you might want to avoid loading the signal as much as possible, so a FET buffer (with 20V tolerant gate) could be a possible solution.

Comment: You could probably characterize the output pretty well with say 1K and 2K resistors to ground when it is supposed to be high, and to 12v (or whatever the observed maximum open circuit voltage is) when it is supposed to be low.  If those resistors don't give you meaningfully different values from which to construct a crude model, try others.

Comment: @TDHofstetter I happen to be using 3K + 1K for a 25% voltage divider.

Comment: @JohnD Is your FET buffer idea similar to Ignacio's Op Amp suggestion?

Comment: @milesb... that sounds like pretty low resistance values to me... what happens if you try the same with about 10x as much resistance for both?

Comment: @milesb Yes, similar idea, buffer the signal so it's not loaded.  You could pull the FET drain up to 3.3V for a 0V-3.3V level translation.  However, Spehro has a great suggestion below, if the output is open collector/drain then there may be nothing but leakage pulling it up, so you may want to characterize the signal as he suggests.

Answer (score 4):

You should try loading the output with something like a 10K resistor, first to ground then to +12V and see what happens. One way or the other you will likely see a reliable logic change, the opposite way you'll see no change in voltage.

Sounds like this might be an industrial standard output that can only source or sink current. If you don't put an appropriate pull-up or pull-down resistor on there, you'll be depending on leakage to give you the proper logic state. Chances are that will **not** be reliable.

Comment: I've just tried 10K to between signal and gnd/+12V in turn. With no other loading, it makes no visible difference.  If I introduce a pair of resistors in a divider, the observable voltage drops to 6V (approx).

Comment: Then you should be able to use 10K + 3.3K resistors to get 25%, no?

Answer (score 0):

Put it through an op amp voltage follower with as low a leakage current as you can reasonably get. This will buffer the voltage enough for you to manipulate it further.

Comment: Interesting - so that might have minimal impact on the source side but allow me to drive an optocoupler onwards?  Would you be able to suggest a suitable part number, please?  I can find a few Op Amps but as far as I can tell they appear to incorporate gain - which I don't think I want.

Comment: All op amps have gain. The trick is to use the voltage follower configuration as described in application note 31.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - Which application note is this? Link?

Comment: @milesb - What the "voltage follower configuration"  Ignacio is referring to is a method of wiring up an op-amp so it has a gain of 1. This means that is basically just outputs the voltage you input, only with the current-driving capability of the op-amp, rather then the input source.